# Cannot insert data to MySQL with Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I 'm working on a web applicaton with Netbeans JAVA (JSPs and Servlets) and MySQL and I am trying to make a "Sign up" feature.

So, from the JSP I call the SignUp Servlet, which calls the PostUserData. The Userbean just keeps the data, so that I can show them again in the JSP easily.

I get error "java.lang.NullPointerException - model.DataManager.PostUserData(DataManager.java:191)", which points where the resultsets close.

```
public UserBean PostUserData(String username, String password, String first_name, String last_name, String email)
                {
                        UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
                        Connection conn = getConnection();
                        if (conn != null) 
                    {
                        ResultSet rs1 = null;
                            ResultSet rs2 = null;
                            PreparedStatement pst1 = null;
                            PreparedStatement pst2 = null;
                            try
                        {
                                        String strQuery1 = "select * from user where uid=?";
                                        pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery1);
                                        pst1.setString(1, username);
                                        rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();
                                        boolean usernameExists = rs1.next();            
                                        if (usernameExists  == false) {    
                                            String student = "student";
                                            String strQuery2 = "INSERT INTO user VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                                            pst2 = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery2);
                                            pst2.setString(1, username);
                                            pst2.setString(2, password);
                                            pst2.setString(3, first_name);          
                                            pst2.setString(4, last_name);
                                            pst2.setString(5, email);
                                            pst2.setString(6, student);
                                            rs2 = pst2.executeQuery();                                                       
                                        } else         
                                            {    
                                               userBean.setUidExists(true);
                                            }   
                        }//end of try
                            catch(SQLException ex)
                            {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            finally 
                            {
                                try 
                                { 
                                    rs1.close();
                                    rs2.close();
                                    pst1.close();
                                    pst2.close();
                                }
                                catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                                putConnection(conn);                
                            }//end of finally 
                        }//end of if
                    return userBean;

                    }
```

I already did a login feature in the same way and it works perfect with my database, so there is not a problem with MySQL. I also tested the Insert Script in MySQL workbench and it worked.

Finally, when I remove the code

```
>                                     rs1.close();
>                                     rs2.close();
>                                     pst1.close();
>                                     pst2.close();
```

outside the try, it checks if the username exists, so the problem is definitely in the INSERT script. Thanks for your time.

Comment: which statment gives you NPE? rs2 can be null if usernameExists=true

Comment: Voted to close - according to OP the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Problem Solved

I replaced `rs2 = pst2.executeQuery();` with

`rs2 = pst2.executeUpdate();`

and it works.

Answer (score 2):

`rs2` is null by default.
It only gets initiated, if the condition `(usernameExists == false)` is `true`.
But I think a record exists and hence `usernameExists` returns a `true` and above condition becomes a `false`. And hence `rs2` remains `null`.

On a `null` pointing reference you can't call any object specific methods.
Otherwise it results a `NullPointerException`. It is the same in your case.

1. Unless required, you need not catch exceptions in finally block.
2. Use `if( rs2 != null ) rs2.close();` in finally block too.

You can take similar cautions on every such object.

Comment: Helpful hint, but the Insert script doesn't work again. If I move the code of the insertion alone in a try-catch, it catches exception. The weird is that when I use the same script in Workbench, it works fine.

Comment: Problem is not in your `insert ...` statement.